# ¿Alguien experto en woocommerce? Tengo un problema con pedidos que se perdiero en una restauración del sitio web 

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Desde el 7/11 tenemos números de orden duplicados con la información cruzada. Para darle solución a eso, contactamos con soporte de `woocommerce` y nos recomendaron instalar un plugin llamado "sequential order number for `woocommerce`" al instalarlo, el plugin nos cambió todos los números de orden, y no pudimos volver a los números de orden originales de otra forma que no fuera restaurando el sitio con una copia de seguridad del 9/11, esto hizo que todos los pedidos del 10/11 al 13/11 (parcialmente) se perdieran.

Luego, dado que el sistema no registraba el número de orden de todos esos pedidos perdidos, y que los nuevos pedidos ingresaban con números de orden repetidos nuevamente, se volvió a instalar el plugin con la solicitud de que no afecte los pedidos actuales. Lo cual no funcionó y volvimos a perder pedidos en la base de `woocommerce`.

Necesitamos con urgencia recuperar esos pedidos y lograr que los nuevos pedidos ingresen con numero de orden nuevo

Comment: No existe un plugin como tal que te ayude con eso, lo que necesitas hacer es descargar la base de datos con todos los pedidos anteriores y la base de datos con todos los pedidos nuevos, unir ambas bases de datos pero en vez de importarlos, exportarlos en un JSON para luego volver a importarlos, de esa forma, woocommerce los tomara como nuevos y generará ID's nuevos para los pedidos, así ya no habrán repetidos, un trabajo algo complejo si no sabes de mysql y el funcionamiento de wordpress y la base de datos.